# How to get the data from mysql database without using webservices like WCFin silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

Is there any other ways so i can get the data from mysql database to show in a datagridview in a Silverlight application without using Webservice like WCF webservice .?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a client side web technology and as such cannot access a database directly. Web services are normally the best way to access the data you want but I guess you could get creative using an elevated trust application and reading from the file system in some kind of hacky way but that's not going to be a good idea!